# Finding pairs in a dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on a data which is in the form of a dataframe. My dataframe is:

```
left_id  right_id

  a         b
  a         c
  c         e
```

I want to code in such a way that I get output as below:

```
 key    value

  a      b,c
  c       e
```

in the input dataframe, a has occurred twice. once with c and once with b. hence the value of a is assigned as both b and c.
For c the value is assigned as e.

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want `groupby.agg` with `join`:

```
df.groupby('left_id').right_id.agg(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: omg! It was so simple and I was stuck in making loops and unnecessary loops.
Thanks a lot for the help. I am new to programming therefore generally get stuck in these issues. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can **groupby** the 'left_id', then call **agg()** functions of Panda’s DataFrame objects on 'right_id'.

The aggregation functionality provided by the **agg()** function allows multiple statistics to be calculated per group in one calculation.

```
df.groupby('left_id', as_index = False).agg({'right_id': ' '.join})
```

Or if you just want to concateate strings into a column of list objects you can also:

```
df.groupby('left_id')['right_id'].apply(list)
```